# Using powershell to recursively pull info

Tags: powershell

I am using mediainfo program to pull info from my files. I can run the following in Powershell and it returns the info I want. What I don't know how to do is recursively go thru every dir and look only at certain extensions. I know I need and include with the extensions I want but not sure how to do it.

The command that works now is:

```
.\mediainfo.i386 --inform=file://x:\stuff.txt x:\pic >>x:\output.txt
```

The `stuff.txt` has the parameters that I am looking for. and `x:\pic` is the dir that contains more dir's with that need to be searched. Then the info is appended to the `output.txt` file. This works on the cmd line but it pulls everything I just want to look for only `.png, .jpg, .bmp` files.

An added benefit would be to put this script in any directory and have it run. I know I would have to put the script and the txt files in the same dir but is there a way to do like dos can with the %1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter to return just the items you're looking for. For example, this will list all the JPG files in the current folder and its subfolders:

```
gci -name -recurse . | ? { $_.Contains(".jpg") } | % { "file: " + $_ }
```

The two key parts are:

- ? -- `Where-Object`, which only passes the names the match to the next item in the pipe
- % -- `Foreach-Object`, which does something with each item in the pipe

As Christian pointed out in the comments, this is more performent:

```
gci -name -recurse . -filter *.jpg | % { "file: " + $_ }
```

I hope this is enough to answer your question.

Comment: `gci -name -recurse . -filter *.jpg` is much more performant.

Comment: thanks, now i try: gci -name -recurse . -filter *.jpg, *.png | % { "file: " + $_ mediainfo.i386 --inform=file://x:\stuff.txt x:\pic >>x:\output.txt } and I get nothing.  do i need the file: stuff?

Comment: No, the "file: " + something syntax prints the filename to the console. I used it as an illustration. Sorry for the confusion.